# Remove Everything In Brackets with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table and some of the elements from the field, "title" have "( some text)". I want to remove the brackets portion of the text.

So

blah blah (blah) would turn into blah blah

How would I do this in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the replace function in MySQL

```
select replace(replace(title,'(', ''),')','') as  title
from table
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: what is element? I never defined it.

I just want to update the table. How would i do this without using element? Thanks

Comment: @sanghan element, title or whatever you have is the name of the column you are selecting from